# how to set tcp.nodelay when i use httpurlconnection

Tags: java, tcp

How to set `tcp.nodelay` for below given code:

```
URL url = new URL(urlText);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware you cannot set `tcp.noDelay` on `HttpURLConnection' as this does not allow any interface to alter underlaying tcp socket.

What I can recommend is try using [Apache http client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) as it provide mechanism to set multiple TCP options. Have a look at this [DefaultHttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html)